# When to use Map and when to use Array/List?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dictionary, dart

I am quite new to flutter and in my tutorial I've learnt to use Maps and Arrays. I know that a Map is pretty much an array but things are identified by a key. When should I be using Maps and when should I be using Arrays? Can you please provide some real examples? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists and https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to store data in key and values then used Map.
eg. contact list. In that, you can store a person's name as a key and phone no as a value.

The array used for only similar data types. we can not store data of multiple data types in the array.